# Graph conductance - program/code/library

Tags: graphs, random-walks

Technical question: is there any open source program/code/library which can compute (minimal) conductance of a given graph, probably by some simulated annealing?

Think it is quite well-known problem, but I cannot find anything like I mentioned above, but maybe you guys know? I know that it is a NP-hard task, but anyway, probably someone has written some programs.

Comment: [Related question on meta.](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/questions/660/is-cs-se-an-appropriate-place-to-ask-for-for-references-to-toolkits-programs-rel)